# How can i show a Drupal block on a specific civi path that contains a question mark

Tags: drupal

Title says it all really. Drupal Blocks don't work with paths that contain question marks

Answer (score 2):

The Drupal module [Block Query](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_query) pretty well nails it, and there is an explanation about using it with civicrm [here](https://www.fuzion.co.nz/blogs/showing-blocks-specific-civi-pages)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.  Just add the Block Query module, then in your block Configuration under Visibility Settings you will now see a Queries. In pages you need to select All or Only and add the civicrm/contribute/transact* then in Queries you select All or Only and add id=8