# Display a Block on a specific Civi contribution page using a url alias (How to)

Tags: drupal

Drupal 7.6
Civi 5.4.1
I would like to display a Block on a Civi contribution page but I would also like to have the page have a pretty url rather than the Civi civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=8
[Here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19040/how-can-i-show-a-drupal-block-on-a-specific-civi-path-that-contains-a-question-m) I found help to add the block as long as I have the native Civi url. Any ideas on how I can display the block with a url alias in place?

Comment: Related: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/87/how-do-i-change-the-default-urls-to-contribution-or-event-registration-pages/146#146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the solution you linked to above and then set up a friendlier redirect that forwards them to the correct internal page URL. (So you could use something like example.org/donate and when they click on it the Redirect would send them to example.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=8) The end result is still the default URL, but you could use the friendlier redirect in emails, campaign materials, etc.

Or, set up a webform (using Webform-CiviCRM) that takes payment/contribution. Then you can set up your own URL as usual (but can't use the default contribution form payment profiles, etc. -- you'd have to set the needed fields up in the webform).

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the simplest option. Use a redirect instead of an alias.